# MySQL tables primary / foreign key to make an id follow

Tags: mysql

Consider theses schemas

```
create table users (

    id int auto_increment not null primary key,

    username varchar(256) not null,

    password varchar(256) not null

);

create table grades (

    id int auto_increment not null,

    username varchar(256) not null,

    assignmentName varchar(256) not null,

    mark int,

    foreign key(id) references users(id)

);
```

Consider this users table:

```
id   username   password
1    a          x 
2    b          x
3    c          x
```

I want the grades table to have the same primary - username relation such that grades tables like below could easily exist,

```
id   username   assignmentname   mark
1    a          a1               10 
1    a          a2               20
3    c          a1               30
```

As you can see the id doesn't change for the user. Is there anyway I can do this? My current way does not work.

INSERT Tables:

```
insert into users values 

(NULL, "a", "x"),
(NULL, "b", "x"),
(NULL, "c", "x");


insert into grades values

(NULL, "a", "a1", 10),
(NULL, "a", "a2", 20),
(NULL, "c", "a1", 30)
```

Comment: So, what is your question ?  and what you have tried ?

Comment: Show you insert query for **grades** table

Comment: So in your insert query for **grades** you want that **username** should be inserted automatically right ?

Comment: This looks like bad design, why have username in both tables? You could have userid in grades and foreign key that to users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have an 'id' that it's autoincrement and foreign key at the same time, you need to change your CREATE statement:

```
create table grades (
    grades_id int not null auto_increment,    
    id int not null,    
    username varchar(256) not null,    
    assignmentName varchar(256) not null,    
    mark int,  
    PRIMARY KEY (`grades_id`),  
    foreign key(id) references users(id)    
);
```

You can do it using the username as foreign key:

```
create table grades (
    id int not null auto_increment,    
    username varchar(256) not null,    
    assignmentName varchar(256) not null,    
    mark int,  
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  
    foreign key(username) references users(username)    
);
```

Comment: How would I insert the grades table without hard coding the id value?

Comment: To do so, you need to use as foreign key the username, i change my answer

Comment: Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake, it should be **foreign key(username) references users(username)**